# Creating new table from a query results

Tags: oracle

I want to create a table of output from this query,Table is giving `USR_ID` Kindly help I'm novice to SQL

```
select USR_ID
from USR,company@,employee
where SK_USR_ID=USR_ID
and Assignedto=employeeID
and SK_Dept_ID=1
and employeeID not in ( '30420','30418')
minus

select USR_ID
from USR,sts_company,employee
where SK_USR_ID=USR_ID
and  Assignedto=employeeID
and SK_Dept_ID=1
and employeeID not in ( '30420','30418')
and USR_ID in (select USR_ID from ENTERPRISE_USR where SK_ENTERPRISE_TYPE_ID= 2 or SK_ENTERPRISE_TYPE_ID= 3 or SK_ENTERPRISE_TYPE_ID=4)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you are a novice I would suggest starting out by using the ANSI join syntax, https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `create table ... as select` approach:

```
create table my_table as 
select USR_ID
from USR,company@,employee
where SK_USR_ID=USR_ID
and Assignedto=employeeID
and SK_Dept_ID=1
and employeeID not in ( '30420','30418')
minus
select USR_ID
from USR,sts_company,employee
where SK_USR_ID=USR_ID
and  Assignedto=employeeID
and SK_Dept_ID=1
and employeeID not in ( '30420','30418')
and USR_ID in (select USR_ID from ENTERPRISE_USR where SK_ENTERPRISE_TYPE_ID= 2 or SK_ENTERPRISE_TYPE_ID= 3 or SK_ENTERPRISE_TYPE_ID=4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer following OP's comments:

You can use the [CREATE TABLE AS...](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table2.php) construct (see the new fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5ee7a2088eebea3b7b9477a3b20ee2f)).

To demonstrate:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, x INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE(x));  

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 45), (2, 46), (3, 47), (4, 48), (5, 49), (6, 50);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE b (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, y INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (y));

INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 48), (2, 49), (3, 50), (4, 51), (5, 52);
```

Then, perform our `MINUS`:

```
CREATE TABLE c AS
(
  SELECT id, x FROM a
  MINUS
  SELECT id, y FROM b
);
```

then:

```
SELECT * FROM c;
```

Result:

```
ID  X
1   45
1   46
1   47
1   49
1   50
```

All's good!

That's the end of the first part of the answer and addresses the question asked:

> I want to create a table of output from this query,

### However, a bit of caution is required. If you do this:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS (SELECT * FROM a);
```

You will then be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 45), (1, 45);
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Result:

```
ID  X
1   45
2   46
3   47
4   48
5   49
5   50
1   45
1   45
```

Your `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints have sailed out the window. You need to remember to modify the results of `CREATE TABLE AS ...`, giving it suitable `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE` and other constraints.

Check the fiddle, but what I did was delete the duplicates in the new table t and then I did this:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_fk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_x_uq UNIQUE (x);
```

So, now we have table t's constraints identical to table a's ones. I then demonstrate that now, with the constraints added, we are no longer able to add either duplicates of the `PRIMARY KEY` id field or the `UNIQUE` x field. This was just to demonstrate that you have to be careful when using `CREATE TABLE xyz AS SELECT...`!

Comment: Are you sure you can create tables a and b with id as primary key without unique constraint violation?

Comment: If `USR_ID`is a `PRIMARY KEY` then you can be guaranteed that your table created by the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT...` will have a unique field - i.e. `USR_ID`. Then do `ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo PRIMARY KEY (USR_ID);`. Now your new table can't have duplicate `USR_ID`s. [Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/primary_keys.php) helped.

Comment: I was referring to your script `CREATE TABLE a (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, y INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (y));` but you can't insert id as 1 for all rows that will violate primary key  and same as with table b

Comment: `SQL> CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, x INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE(x));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 45);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 46);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 46)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C008922) violated`

Comment: The point of the demo was to show that caution is required when using `CREATE TABLE xyz AS (SELECT * FROM abc);` because any constraints on xyz are not carried over to the new table in the `CREATE TABLE...` step - it's a bit of a "gotcha" for those new to databases - I got caught myself a couple of times! I've revised my answer and the fiddle that goes with it. My original was wrong and more than a bit confusing - apologies for that!